# Autodesk InventorApprentice API print .iam or .ipt to PDF

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Using examples for the Autodesk Inventor Aprentice API I can print a 2d .IDW file to PDF

But I cannot get a model (.IAM/.IPT) to do so

InventorView can print to the MS Print to PDF from the app, so it is possible

Any ideas or guidance appreciated

```
    public void PrintModelToPdf(string iam, string outputFolder)
    {
        string logFileName = Path.Combine(outputFolder, "PrintPDFlog.txt");
        string modelName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(iam);
        string pdfFileName = Path.Combine(outputFolder, $"{modelName}.pdf");

        try
        {
            InventorApprentice.ApprenticeServerComponent apprentice = new ApprenticeServerComponent();
            apprentice.Open(iam);

            InventorApprentice.ApprenticeServerDocument model;
            model = apprentice.Document;

            model.PrintManager.Printer = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
            model.PrintManager.Orientation = PrintOrientationEnum.kDefaultOrientation;
            model.PrintManager.PaperSize = PaperSizeEnum.kPaperSizeESheet;
            model.PrintManager.NumberOfCopies = 1;
            model.PrintManager.ColorMode = PrintColorModeEnum.kPrintDefaultColorMode;

            //Throws with "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"
            model.PrintManager.PrintToFile(pdfFileName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logFileName, $"{ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the question on the Inventor API forum - that's where you're most likely to get help: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-ilogic-and-vb-net-forum/bd-p/120
Also, the "autodesk-viewer" tag is about the web based Viewer https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/overview/